# Why is my GSP pulling in my AngularJS javascript files but not executing my controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, grails-resources-plugin

I have a simple GSP View which contains a reference to 2 bundles being managed by the Grails Resources plugin.

the reference to the core angularjs libraries are in my layout.

A basic representation of the view is like so:

```
<html ng-application="myapp">
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>a title</title>
<r:require modules="index, widgeta"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="index"> 
<div>
    <widgeta/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Grails seems to pull everything in just fine, i can even see the myapp.controller('index', function(){}); line get executed.

However; my controller function itself never gets executed. Why not!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly grails... I took a closer look at what was coming back with the HTML and grails was stripping off the controller and app reference.

Moving both to the first 'div' tag in the body seem to do the trick:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>a title</title>
<r:require modules="index, widgeta"/>
</head>
<body> 
<div ng-application="myapp" ng-controller="index">
    <widgeta/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: grails did not really strip the ng's, the reason `ng-application` and `ng-controller` are not there is that the `htlm` and `body` element are taken from the layout.

Comment: Right. Which effectively strips it.